# Add properties to every control with a specific name/pattern in the ID - ASP.NET (VB)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, for-loop

I have several controls on a page that contain the word "DATE" in the ID. These are specific text boxes for dates only.

Here is an example of what I need to do for each text box control with "DATE" in the ID:

***Birth***_Date.Text = fnLib.formatDate(***Birth***_Date.Text, 1)

***Anniversary***_Date.Text = fnLib.formatDate(***Anniversary***_Date.Text, 1)

Rather than do this for every single control, is there a way I could do this in some kind of For Each Loop? I am fairly new to ASP.Net (VB) so I am still learning. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you could do this with a loop, something pseudocoded like this.

```
foreach(Control currentControl in this.Controls)
{
   var currentTextbox = currentControl as TextBox;
   if(currentTextbox != null && currentTextbox.Id.EndsWith("_Date"))
     //DO your stuff here
}
```

But honestly I'm not sure that is going to get you much, especially if there are lots of other controls...As this has to attempt to cast the item to the target type first.  WHich if you have a lot of failures, could be a big performance hit.

Comment: You could reduce the performance hit by testing the Id before the attempt to cast since Id is a property on Control. You should also take into account container controls (controls that can host other controls) and perform this method recursively using the Controls collection on each control.

Comment: @Mitchell Sellers - Any chance this could be converted to VB as I'm not familiar with C# and I've tried to run it through a converter but it fails? Thanks

Comment: @james - let me get to Visual Studio and I'll get it converted for you.  (My VB is rusty...)